# Could not resolve dependencies, Failed to read artifact descriptor, Failed to collect dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

There is a project myProject that has two modules and moduleB has a dependency on moduleA. moduleA builds successfully and is deployed on nexus but when  you try to deploy moduleB you get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project moduleB: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:moduleB:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT 
Failed to collect dependencies at groupId:moduleA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for groupId:moduleA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact groupId:myProject:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
Failed to execute goal on project moduleB: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:moduleB:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
Failed to collect dependencies at groupId:moduleA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Or sometimes this one:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project moduleB: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project groupId:moduleB:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT 
Failed to collect dependencies at groupId:moduleA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for groupId:moduleA:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:
Failure to find groupId:myProject:pom:360 
in http://lonrs07557:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/  was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval 
of myProject_maven_repo has elapsed or updates are forced.
```

I've looked around for solutions but I get different errors each time and it gets chaotic. I've tried doing a clean -U, a dependency tree, an effective pom and many more (unsuccessfully). My maven repo is set up correctly:

```
   <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>nexus repository</name>
            <url>http://lonrs07557:8081/nexus/content/groups/repo</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  [...]
  <distributionManagement>
        <site>
            <id>lonrs07557-docs</id>
            <name>Documentation Repository</name>
            <url>scp://lonrs07557:9999/content/maven/site-documentation</url>
        </site>
        <repository>
             <id>lonrs07557-releases</id>
             <name>Release Repository</name>
             <url> dav:http://lonrs07557:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
       </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>lonrs07557-snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>dav:http://lonrs07557:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

> One of the problems is that is looking for an older version of the master pom (although that older version it's not referenced anywhere).
>
> There is another warning that a pom is missing, however I can see it in nexus.

```
[WARNING] The POM for groupId:log-util:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, 
no dependency information available
```

Also when I was building locally everything was successful, when I was doing it later on through TeamCity it was failing upon the aforementioned, so in my efforts to reproduce the problem locally, I deleted my local maven repo and it got forced to create a new one which resulted in the same errors. Then I worked around this problem by actually building moduleA first and then moduleB. However, I cannot use the same workaround when I do it throught the TeamCity agent.

The way I'm running it (locally and in TeamCity) is:

```
mvn clean deploy -f moduleB/pom.xml -U -X
```

settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>c:/maven/repository</localRepository>
<pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
        <pluginGroup>com.totsp.gwt</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>lonrs07563-docs</id>
            <username>XXXXX</username>
            <password>XXXXX</password>
            <configuration>
            <knownHostsProvider
                implementation="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.NullKnownHostProvider">
                <hostKeyChecking>no</hostKeyChecking>
            </knownHostsProvider>
            </configuration>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>lonrs07557-releases</id>
            <username>XXXXX</username>
            <password>XXXXX</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>lonrs07557-snapshots</id>
            <username>XXXXX</username>
            <password>XXXXX</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>myProject_maven_repo</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://lonrs07557:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <clusterport>${env.MYPROJECT_CLUSTER_PORT}</clusterport>
                <clusteraddress>${env.MYPROJECT_CLUSTER_ADDRESS}</clusteraddress>
                <hostname>${env.hostname}</hostname>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: I do define one. 
<dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Several flaws: You have a `groupId` called "groupId"? Strange. Second: You obviously want to bring _snapshots_ into your repository, but the repository you enabled is a _release_ repo. Maybe that's your problem. It just isn't there, where Maven looks.

Comment: the naming convention is such since I'm not at liberty to share the actual names!

Comment: And what about `http://57:8081/nexus`? There are some characters missing ...

Comment: Do you have a mirror element in your settings.xml? If so, show us, please. Additionally, where is the repository element defined? In your settings or in a POM? Third: The element for distribution management is only for uploading, but is not used for dependency resolution.

Comment: I updated the maven repo comment in the post to reflect reality - I had there already.
About settings.xml, I do:
`<mirrors>
     <mirror>
         <id>myProject_maven_repo</id>
         <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
         <url>http://lonrs07557:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
     </mirror>
 </mirrors>`

Comment: You did not show the repo where Maven tries to _resolve_ artifacts. You have updated it with information about distribution management. This is for _uploading_.

Comment: Additionally, you should have a mirror with an id of `central`, pointing to the _public group_ of your company repo manager (Nexus). In fact you defined a mirror with an ID that does not have a corresponding repository definition.

Comment: Having said this: Please show me the complete settings.xml and the complete pom.xml for the project in question (of course you can guard some credentials, if you want). I then will be able to correct them for you.

Comment: so I cannot show you the complete pom.xml since is 1500 lines long, and I couldn't guard all of these credentials! I'll edit the post for settings.xml

Comment: Ok. Your settings look ok now! You are mirroring every remote repo (the `*`). This mirror points to the public group of your repo manager. You should make sure, that both repos - the releases and the snapshot hosting repos - are part of this group (among others). In fact, you do not need any defined repositories. It does not make sense to define any, as they would be mirrored to your nexus repo anyway. So please remove the defined repository with the id `nexus` (wherever it sits). Afterwards a `mvn -U ...` should now resolve your artifacts (`-U` does a _force update_).

Comment: I would recommend to change the `mirrorOf` entry to not being `*`, but being `central`. This is the remote repository that Maven connects to by default. Mirroring that to your own Nexus is what usually should be done. But now you are free to define further repositories, either in the settings.xml or in any project's POM, which then will be picked up if anything is not found in your Nexus (which might be handy sometimes).

Comment: That was really helpful, however I still need to go and build the modules separately and the parent pom (i.e. moduleD - there are more dependencies than I let on) still fails. So given this
`moduleD -> moduleC -> moduleB -> moduleA`
1. A,B, C build successfully but D fails. 
2. I don't understand why for example module C doesn't work unless I build A and B separately.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the versions since when I deploy locally module A,B and C *1.0-SNAPSHOT* version is created, however when I deploy module D an actual version (e.g. *10.0.1.5623*) is generated and it goes to look for artifacts that are not there, since they are listed under a different version.

Comment: If you have a project that consists of several projects, which should be built in a defined order, then you should make another pom-typed project called an [aggregator](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Aggregation). And - regarding your last comment - you should take care of the versions. If project D is not a snapshot one, it might be that it also does not depend on snapshots.

Comment: I do have an aggregator pom (which is what I was referring to as moduleD). Any idea why the javadocs.jar for the dependent modules would get generated for version 1.0-SNAPSHOT but not for the actual version?